# Out of three different fields find the nearest value of X

Tags: python, fields-attributes

I have 4 Fields.

FFE,
year10,
year50,
year100

I created a 5th field and labeled it - CP

I need help writing a python script in field calculator to fill the column CP with whatever FFE is closest to out of year10, year50, year100.

Example:

FFE = 45

year10 = 35

year50 = 51

year100 = 60

Desired result would be - CP = year50

Comment: Which field calculator are you using? QGIS, ArcGIS for Desktop, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Right click your column and select field calculator. Under field calculator select Show Codeblock.

```
def findClosest(FFE, year10, year50, year100):
      choices = [abs(FFE - year10), abs(FFE - year50), abs(FFE - year100)] 
      if choices[0] == min(choices):
        return "year10"
      elif choice[1] == min(choices):
        return "year50"
      elif choice[2] == min(choices)
        return "year100"
```

Then in the line below
CP = 
findClosest(!FFE!, !year10!, !year50!, !year100!)

Comment: It seem the asker needs the return value be a string (e.g. "year100")